# DataContractJsonSerializer : unserializing an object which can be a string or an object

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone, windows-8.1

I'm currently retrieve some datas from an API which sends me a array. The object "params" is a string in the first element, but is an object is the second one.

My DataContract looks like this :

```
[DataMember(Name = "params")]
string Params;

[DataMember(Name = "params")]
ParamsJson Params2;
```

(ParamsJson just contains a string DataMember).

I read Json.NET or Newton can resolve my problem, but I really want to solve without adding a new library.

Answer (score 0):

I may find a solution which will work.

Instead of a double declaration, it's better to list all the types in an enumeration.